# Representing multiple element names in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the below XML which represents a call event and needs to be unmarshalled to a Java object. I'm using JAXB and able to handle most of it except the  block which represents a collection of values as element names.

Short of creating a class for every possible element (ie. as given [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html)) is there a way to represent this in JAXB more dynamically?

```
<message xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.server.example.com' to='leon@server.example.com'
id='leon_office_vmstsp_default__leon@server.example.com__uz8mQ'>
<event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
    <items node='leon_office_vmstsp_default'>
        <item id='leon_office_vmstsp_default'>
            <callstatus xmlns='http://xmpp.org/protocol/openlink:01:00:00#call-status'
                busy='false'>
                <call>
                    <id>1411743786867</id>
                    <profile>leon_office</profile>
                    <interest>leon_office_vmstsp_default</interest>
                    <changed>State</changed>
                    <state>CallEstablished</state>
                    <direction>Outgoing</direction>
                    <duration>3</duration>
                    <caller>
                        <number>6001</number>
                        <name>leon_office</name>
                    </caller>
                    <called>
                        <number>3807</number>
                        <name>3807</name>
                    </called>
                    <actions>
                        <ClearCall />
                        <RemoveThirdParty />
                        <StopVoiceDrop />
                        <MuteParty />
                        <AddThirdParty />
                        <SendDigit />
                        <ClearConnection />
                        <UnMuteParty />
                        <StartVoiceDrop />
                    </actions>
                    <participants>
                        <participant exten='3807' />
                        <participant exten='6001' />
                    </participants>
                    <features>
                        <feature id='Conference'>true</feature>
                    </features>
                </call>
            </callstatus>
        </item>
    </items>
</event>
<headers xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/shim'>
    <header name='pubsub#subid'>aLfatHpG059mNcAe5ta11YNOAjA02l486sE1p4hK</header>
</headers>
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

**JAXB java classes generation**

1. Generate an XSD from your XML. You can use also [this link](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) or another tool works fine.
2. Generate classes from XSD by XJC, Maven plugin [see here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide)

Below en example of `maven-jaxb2-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
            <arg>-nv</arg>
        </args>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
        <bindingIncludes>
            <include>*.xjb</include>
        </bindingIncludes>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.xsd</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope it can help you.